# How to find out what form is on top?

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework

In Compact Framework, how can I find out which form is the form that is showing to the user (even if it is not full screen)?

Any ideas?  I will keep looking and post back if I find an answer (and no one responds).

Comment: GetForegroundWindow() should work. take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932991.aspx alternatively you can use OpenNetCF which is a .NET CF wrapper for Win CE APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example from http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetForegroundWindow.html:

```
public ApplicationState AppState
{
    get
    {
        Process[] processCollection = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName);
        if(processCollection != null && processCollection.Length  >= 1 && 
            processCollection[0] != null)
        {
            IntPtr activeWindowHandle = Win32.GetForegroundWindow();
            //Optional int ProcessID;
            //Optional Win32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(),out ProcessID)
            foreach(Process wordProcess in processCollection)
            {
                //Optional if( ProcessID == wordProcess.Id ) return ApplicationState.Focused;
                if(wordProcess.MainWindowHandle == activeWindowHandle)
                {
                    return ApplicationState.Focused;
                }
            }
            return ApplicationState.Running;
        }
        return ApplicationState.NotRunning;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can p/invoke GetForegroundWindow to find the current window.